# how to write the joint pmf of bivariate distribution which defined over more than one interval in r

Tags: r, function, plot, plotly

[definition of the bivariate distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3V5Z.png)
If I have the following joint probability density function:
[The joint PMF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aj3T.png)
i.e, the **joint** probability mass function (pmf) is consisting of the following pmf and cumulative distribution function
[The marginal pmf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzyCM.png)

The R code of the marginal distribution is given as follows (i.e the pmf of DIW distribution)

```
ddiw<- function(x, t, eta){  # t means theta parameter
  stopifnot( eta>0, x>=0)
  pmf<-t^(x+1)^(-eta) - t^(x)^(-eta)
  return(pmf)
}
```

Its cumulative distribution function in R  is as follows

```
pdiw<-function(x, t, eta){
  stopifnot(  eta > 0)
  cdf<- t^(x+1)^(-eta)
  return(cdf) 
}
```

I want to write the joint pmf in R as in equation (4).
I tried to write the joint pmf in equation (4) in R, but I did not succeed.
Also, I want to plot the joint pmf in R as in the following figure
[3D plot of bivariate distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qerqL.png)

could you help me to write the joint pmf in R and plot it as in the given figure.

Thanks in advance.

> Edit

I write the joint pmf to be more clear as follows
[The joint pmf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiSpz.png)

[The joint pmf when substituting the pmf of DIW and substituting cdf of DIW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBh8T.png)

Comment: The problem for me seems to be the definition of e.g. `f1` after equation 4. What is zeta? Maybe this is a question for [crossvalidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @KarstenW. the problem for me, I do not know how can we write the joint pmf (like the given joint pmf ) in R, I searched alot in google to find R code for this type of joint pmf. Again my question is how can write this joint pmf in R? Any help you could provide would be much appreciated.

Comment: @KarstenW. I edited my question and I write in detail the joint pmf

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is helpful, but you could write the function along the lines:

```
joint_pmf <- function(x1, x2, eta) {
    stopifnot(
        all(x1>0), all(x2>0), 
        all(is.finite(x1)), all(is.finite(x2)),
        length(x1)==length(x2)
    )
    # the result vector
    n <- length(x1)
    pmf <- rep(NA, n) 

    # check for the first condition
    idx <- which(x1<x2)
    pmf[idx] <- NA # here you need to fill in

    # check for the second condition
    idx <- which(x1>x2)
    pmf[idx] <- NA # here you need to fill in

    # and so on..
}
```

This function accepts vectors for the `x1, x2` arguments. Since the pmf is defined piecewise, the result is computed for subsets only.